# Animate cursor when standing still

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to have a custom cursor and animate it (making it big, then small, then big again) when the mouse has stopped moving after some time? I don't know if this is doable through CSS or Javascript. I know this can be done with CSS when hovering over an element but I don't know if it can be done when the mouse is at rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an event listener that listens for mouse movement, which resets a timer when the mouse is moved. if the mouse is not moved for some time, the timer runs out and a change of the cursor is triggered. when the mouse is moved again, you also change the cursor.

```
var timeout;
document.onmousemove = function(){
  //mouse was moved -> reset cursor
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // mouse stopped -> set cursor
  }, 1000);
}
```

For a more complete example with actually changing the cursor see the following JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7Lb1ro9u/11/

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot